# WSO2 micro integrator email connector list always return empty list

Tags: email, wso2, connector, wso2-micro-integrator

I have been using **Email Connector 1.1.1** to list the emails from AWS Workmail using IMAPS connection.
It returns like this

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <emails />
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My list configuration is as below

```xml
 <email.list configKey="imapsconnection">
        <deleteAfterRetrieve>false</deleteAfterRetrieve>
        <folder>{$ctx:folder}</folder>
    </email.list>
```

It works with send function but list does not.